# Eclipse CDT: Define quoted string as preprocessor define

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse CDT C++ project that has a bunch of unit tests. The tests need access to data that I put in a `data` directory in the same directory. I wanted to use a preprocessor define `-Dtest_data_dir="<path/to/data/dir>"` to specify the data directory to use.

It looks like this won't work due to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309158) in eclipse. Given that, what is the best way to accomplish this? I could hard code the path to the data directory but then I'll have problems with out of source builds not finding the directory.

Comment: Q: What happened when you tried it?  Q: What platform are you on (Windows? Linux?), and what version of Eclipse and (presumably) g++ are you using?

Comment: It is eclipse kepler on OS X and linux. Compiler is g++ 4.8. But the issue is eclipse and specifically that bug. What happens is exactly what is described in the linked bug report. Eclipse strips the quotes from the defined string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked bug report in question provides the answer.  Since I just encountered the issue myself and Google brought me here first...

The answer is to escape your double-quoted string in single quotes. ie:

```
-Dtest_data_dir='"<path/to/data/dir>"'
```